# Let maven generate the Required-Bundles Header?

Tags: maven, manifest

I want to let maven to create the header field `Require-Bundle` depending on my dependencies specified in the `pom.xml`.
I looked into the `maven-jar-plugin` but it does only support generation of the ClassPath header.

Does anyone know a maven plugin that can automatically generate the `RequireBundle` entry in the manifest out of my pom dependencies of scope `provided`?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html).

**ADDENDUM:**

More precisely, maven-bundle-plugin would only assist you when defining the dependencies of your bundle. It would **not** automatically construct a set of required bundles. This is because requiring bundles is not the recommended OSGi practice: you should depend on exported packages. For this reason, maven-bundle-plugin automatically fills the Import-Package, but would not do the same for Require-Bundle (either one or the another, anyway). Hence if you choose to take this road, you'll have to specify bundles manually anyway.

This does not count as a solution, but I thought it worth of discussion.

Comment: I assume I need to use the Require-Bundle instruction, but how can I define that the maven-bundle-plugin should use my maven dependencies of scope "provided" for generating the header? I found only samples defining a static set of required bundles within this instruction...